# Modify product price in WooCommerce cart

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a shop where we put on discount if products are bought in bulk (the bulk offers differ between products). That part is sorted.

Currently, I apply discount using negative fees like this:

```
function sale_custom_price($cart_object) { 
  foreach ($cart_object->cart_contents as $p) {
    $prod_id = $p['product_id'];
    $prod_n = $p['quantity'];
    $prod_price = $p['data']->price;
    $prod_name = $p['data']->post->post_title;
    $prod_total = $p['line_total'];

    /*
    calc_discount: NULL for no discount for this product
                   else
                     array(
                      n => how many are required, e.g. 12
                      free_pcs_deal => how many of these should be free, e.g. 1
                     )
    */
    $discount = calc_discount($prod_id, $prod_n);

    if (is_null($discount)) {
      continue;
    }

    $discount_n = $discount['n'];
    $free_pcs_deal = $discount['free_pcs_deal'];

    if ($discount_n <= 0) {
      continue;
    }

    $discount_txt = $prod_name . ' (' . $discount_n . ' x ' . $free_pcs_deal . ' stk.)';
    $discount = -1 * $discount_n * $free_pcs_deal * $prod_price;

    $cart_object->add_fee('Rabat: ' . $discount_txt, $discount, true, '');
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'sale_custom_price', 2, 1);
```

But that is not supported and is going to be made impossible in the future. So instead, I would like to automatically adjust the product price.

Say a customer buys 12 pieces of product A. The normal price is 100, but product A has a bulk deal of buy 12, pay only for 11 (buy 11-get-one-free). So currently, the product price is 12*100 = 1200, and a negative fee of 100. So the average product price is 11*100/12 = 91.67 for all 12 product A. I would like this to be used in my cart.

But I cannot get it to work with showing the modified price in the cart and also the correct line_total and line_subtotal and order total. So it seems like I haven't found the right `action`/`filter`.

I have tried something like this:

```
$cart = WC()->cart->cart_contents;

foreach ($cart as $key => $p) {
  $custom_price = 111; // of course replaced by logic calculating the new, modified price
  WC()->cart->cart_contents[$key]['data']->price = $custom_price;
}
```

I have tried this logic in `woocommerce_cart_updated`, `woocommerce_before_cart_contents`, `woocommerce_add_to_cart` and others but it will not show a correct cart with updated price, line_total, order total etc.

I can calculate and display the updated price via the `woocommerce_cart_item_price` hook, but that is only the display, it is not in the business logic so that all the totals are modified.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing price customization before you calculate totals. You can use this hook "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" and lower the priority of hook so that any other plugin/customization does not overwrite it.

Here is a piece of code you can customize as needed:

```
function calculate_custom_price( $cart_object ) {

    // Loop for all products in cart
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        if(isset($value['_custom_customized']) && !empty($value['_custom_customized']) && (!isset($isProcessed) || empty($isProcessed))) {
            $fltCustomPrice = 0.00;
            $quantity = intval( $value['quantity'] );
            $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );

            // For all sub products of build your own basket
            foreach($value['_custom_customized'] AS $keyInner => $arrValInner) {
                $fltCustomPrice += floatval($arrValInner['price']) * floatval($arrValInner['quantity']);
            }
            $cart_object->cart_contents[$key]['data']->price = ( $orgPrice + $fltCustomPrice );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_custom_price', 2, 1 );
```

Comment: It does update the price in the cart object, but not the line_total etc. in displaying the cart.

I have used this:
    function calculate_custom_price($cart_object) {
      foreach ($cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value) {
        $cart_object->cart_contents[$key]['data']->price = 5;
      }
      
      echo '<!--';  
      print_r(WC()->cart);
      echo '-->';
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_custom_price', 2, 1 );

price = 5 is printed, but not when displaying the cart html page.

So it seems like the update is done too late.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function on_display_cart_item_price_html($html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {

            if (is_cart()) {
                $price_adjusted = 10; // your adjustments here
                $price_base = $cart_item['data']->sale_price;
                if (!empty($price_adjusted)) {
                    if (intval($price_adjusted) > 0) {
                        $_qnty = $cart_item['quantity'];
                        $cart_item['data']->set_price($price_base - ($price_adjusted / $_qnty));
                        $html = '<del>' . wc_price($price_base) . '</del><ins> ' . wc_price($price_base - ($price_adjusted / $_qnty)) . '</ins>';
                    } else {
                        $html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price($price_base) . '</span>';
                    }
                }
            }

            return $html;
        }


add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'on_display_cart_item_price_html', 100, 3);


    function change_woocommerce_cart_subtotal( $cart_subtotal, $compound, $cart ) { 
        $cart_subtotal = 5;
        return $cart_subtotal; 
    }; 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'change_woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 10, 3 ); 


    // define the woocommerce_order_amount_total callback 
    function change_woocommerce_order_amount_total( $order_total ) { 

        $order_total = 5;
        return $order_total; 
    }; 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'change_woocommerce_order_amount_total' );
```

Try this code snippet in your active theme's functions.php

Comment: This only changes the printed html, not the price in the cart business logic.

Comment: Thanks, but then I override all logic (fee, freight, tax, ...). Hence I would need to either reimplement that or save given discount in session and substract that from total provided to function as argument. This is bound to give errors. Hence, the best (most fault tolerant) would be to change product price early in the workflow and let the WooC engine do as it usually do.

Comment: That you can use this hook "woocommerce_get_price"

Comment: It doesn't work either, but looking at code it seems like it should. I have a suspicion that one of my plugins are causing troubles, maybe it is because I am also using Role Based Pricing.